# Remove duplicate commas and extra commas at start/end with RegExp in Javascript, and remove duplicate numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

Assume we have a string like the following :

```
,34,23,4,5,634,23,12,5,4,3,1234,23,54,,,,,,,123,43,2,3,4,5,3424,,,,,,,,123,,,1234,,,,,,,45,,,56
```

How can we convert it to the following string with RegExp in Javascript ?

```
34,23,4,5,634,12,3,1234,54,123,43,2,3424,45,56
```

Actually, I wanna remove repeated items and first and last `,` char

Comment: uh, where'd the "34" go?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard it must have jumped overboard XD anyways, i think RegExp is not the tool for this job. i think you should parse it instead.

Comment: I agree that it's not the right tool for the job; something starting with the "split" method on strings is probably the way to go.

Comment: You cannot remove the duplicate numbers solely with a regular expression.

Comment: @Samuel Edwin Ward : I forgot it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[edited] To turn these into a set of unique numbers, as you are actually asking for, do this:

```
function scrapeNumbers(string) {
    var seen = {};
    var results = [];
    string.match(/\d+/g).forEach(function(x) {
        if (seen[x]===undefined)
            results.push(parseInt(x));
        seen[x] = true;
    });
    return results;
}
```

Demo:

```
> scrapeNumbers(',1,22,333,22,,333,4,,,')
[1, 22, 333, 4]
```

If you had an `Array.prototype.unique()` primitive, you could write it like so in one line:

```
yourString.match(/\d+/g).map(parseBase10).unique()
```

Unfortunately you need to be a bit verbose and define your own `parseBase10 = function(n){return parseInt(n)}` due to this ridiculous hard-to-track-down bug: [javascript - Array#map and parseInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-array-map-and-parseint)

Comment: That will remove duplicate commas quite nicely, but I believe the questioner wants to remove duplicate numbers as well.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: oh, interesting, you should edit the bad question then rather than downvoting ;-)

Comment: I agree the question isn't very well stated, but did you even read it? Does your code produce anything resembling his example?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: It does now.

Comment: It's still not a string though :)  But I withdraw my downvote.  Nothing personal of course.

Comment: shouldn't it be `parseInt(n,10)` to actually be "parseBase10"?

Comment: @ajax333221: That would indeed make it explicit. However the base defaults to 10 except in cases where the number begins with '0x' (parsed as binary) or '0' (parsed as octal); thus it is unnecessary unless you expect numbers of the form `..,012,..`, in which case you would want to make that explicit. This is however not an issue which is related to this particular problem, as it would occur whenever you use the `parseInt` function in javascript, nomatter the context. It is an example of bad language design.

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex. Few tricks

```
text = ',34,23,4,5,634,23,12,5,4,3,1234,23,54,,,,,,,123,43,2,3,4,5,3424,,,,,,,,123,,,1234,,,,,,,45,,,56';
text = text.replace(/,+/g, ','); //replace two commas with one comma
text = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); //remove the spaces
textarray = text.split(","); // change them into array
textarray = textarray.filter(function(e){ return e.length});
console.log(textarray);                                       


// Now use a function to make the array unique
Array.prototype.unique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(this[i] in u)
         continue;
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}

textarray = textarray.unique();
text = textarray.join(','); //combine them back to what you want
console.log(text);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/QjR3T/3/)

If you are familier with jQuery

```
text = text.replace(/,+/g, ',');
text = $.trim(text);
text = $.unique(text.split(",")).filter(function(e){ return e.length}).join(",");
console.log(text);
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/QjR3T/4/)

Comment: Good lord that phpjs code is really terrible.  Your suggestion is basically correct but really nobody should use that stuff; it appears to have been written by somebody only barely familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy, On that case, updated with a prototype function. Hope you like it.

Comment: The prototype function is perfectly reasonable. However, won't the empty string `''` also be included in the results, and recombined into an arbitrary position?

Comment: @ninjagecko, How about it now? May be you will remove the downvote now

Comment: @Starx: I'm not sure why you thought I downvoted you. Was someone else.

Comment: @ninjagecko, I am sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: on the last jQuery example, you didn't prevent commas at the beginning/end

Comment: @ajax333221, I have filtered at the third line. Please note

Comment: These Lines were very useful to me. `text = text.replace(/,+/g, ',');` and `text = $.trim(text);`... That combination worked very well. thx

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
function arrIndex(fnd, arr) {
    for (var len = arr.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in arr && arr[i] === fnd) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function scrapeNumbers(str) {
    var arr = str.replace(/,+/g, ",").replace(/^,/, "").replace(/,$/, "").split(",");

    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length, rtn = []; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in arr && arrIndex(arr[i], rtn) == -1) {
            rtn.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return rtn.join(",");
}

var str = ",,34,23,4,5,634,23,12,5,4,3,1234,23,54,,,,,,,123,43,2,3,4,5,3424,,,,,,,,123,,,1234,,,,,,,45,,,56,,";

alert(scrapeNumbers(str));
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seNy4/3/)

**Note:** I created a custom `array.indexOf` function for a better [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility)