# What's wrong with parseInt?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript - Array.map and parseInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-array-map-and-parseint)

I stumbled across the following code snippet:

```
> ['10','10','10','10','10'].map(parseInt);
[10, NaN, 2, 3, 4]
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Some diggin' and you'll find this https://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2013/01/madness.md. Google, your best friend.

Comment: Did JavaScript classes start this week? We just had this yesterday.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start by consulting the documentation for [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The key is this line:

> callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element, **the index of the element**, and the Array object being traversed.

(emphasis mine)

Then check the documentation for [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses it, and returns an integer or NaN. If not NaN, the returned value will be the decimal integer representation of the first argument taken as a number in the specified radix (base). For example, a radix of 10 indicates to convert from a decimal number, 8 octal, 16 hexadecimal, and so on. For radices above 10, the letters of the alphabet indicate numerals greater than 9. For example, for hexadecimal numbers (base 16), A through F are used.

and:

> If radix is undefined or 0, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal).
> - If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal). This feature is non-standard, and some implementations deliberately do not support it (instead using the radix 10). For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.
> - If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

So the first call is:

```
parseInt('10',0, ['10','10',...]) // => 10 (because radix=0)
```

the second is:

```
parseInt('10',1, ['10','10',...]) // => NaN because radix is 1
```

the third:

```
parseInt('10',2, ['10','10',...]) // => 2 because 10 in binary is the number "2"
```

and so on.

Answer (score 5):

From [MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case):

> parseInt is often used with one argument, but takes two. The second being the radix
>   To the callback function, Array.prototype.map passes 3 arguments: the element, the index, the array
>   The third argument is ignored by parseInt, but not the second one, hence the possible confusion.

So actually your `parseInt` is passed the folowing values:

```
// 1st run:
parseInt( '10', 0 );
// 2nd run:
parseInt( '10', 1 );
// etc.
```

So you're using a different radix every time, leading to the results seen.