# unexpected "map" result (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Can someone explain why this has the unexpected result:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt);
```

which returns [1, NaN, NaN] instead of [1, 2, 3]？

I can make it work by forcing a single-argument function:

```
["1", "2", "3"].map(function(s) {return parseInt(s);});
```

but I don't know what exactly went wrong in the first way.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, the problem is due to the 2nd argument.

Comments from **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case)**:

```
// parseInt is often used with one argument, but takes two. The second being the radix
// To the callback function, Array.prototype.map passes 3 arguments: the element, the index, the array
// The third argument is ignored by parseInt, but not the second one, hence the possible confusion.
// See the blog post for more details
```

But, with the use of [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), you can achieve the desired result:

```
var _parseInt = function(radix, number) {
  return parseInt(number, radix);
}
["1", "2", "3"].map(_parseInt.bind(this, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

this article describes your issue in its last sample, exactly the same what you are trying to do. However the blog article they refer to doesn't exist anymore.

[array.map() and parseInt callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

A better answer cited from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/262511/2519566):

> So if you call a function which actually expects two arguments, the
>   second argument will be the index of the element.
>
> In this case, you ended up calling parseInt with radix 0, 1 and 2 in
>   turn. The first is the same as not supplying the parameter, so it
>   defaulted to base 10. Base 1 is an impossible number base, and 3 is
>   not a valid number in base 2:

```
parseInt('1', 0); // OK - gives 1
parseInt('2', 1); // FAIL - 1 isn't a legal radix
parseInt('3', 2); // FAIL - 3 isn't legal in base 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` takes two arguments (the second being the radix), that's why this doesn't work. See the bottom of this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more information. Cited:

> parseInt is often used with one argument, but takes two. The second
>   being the radix To the callback function, Array.prototype.map passes 3
>   arguments: the element, the index, the array. The third argument is
>   ignored by parseInt, but not the second one, hence the possible
>   confusion.