# Why ["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt) -> [ 1, NaN, NaN ]

Tags: javascript

I have read Armin Ronacher's  [Stop Being Cute and Clever](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/12/9/stop-being-clever/) article, where he gives this example of strange implementation of `.map()` in JavaScript, but he has no explanation for this and I am quite curious, because it does not make sense to me. So, why

```
console.log(["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt))
```

outputs:

```
[ 1, NaN, NaN ]
```

Comment: Funny, but this is working: `console.log(["1", "2", "3"].map(function(el) { return parseInt(el); }))`.

Comment: Because `parseInt` takes a second parameter that `map` expects to be the index, but it's not, it's the "radix". On the other hand, `parseFloat` will work just fine.

Comment: The oldest dupe is actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint and it has an excellent accepted answer.