# Arrary map strange behavor

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am tring to use parseInt in a `map`, but some strange behavor happened,
here is code:

```
["1","2"].map(parseInt)
```

the result is:

```
[1, NaN]
```

but when I wrap the `parseInt` function:

```
["1","2"].map(function(n){ return parseInt(n)})
```

it works fine, the result is:

```
[1, 2]
```

why?

Comment: I suspect it's related to `parseInt` taking two input parameters. You can see the same behavior by modifying your wrapper function to take in `(n, m)`. On the other hand, `parseFloat` works as expected, and it only takes one parameter.

Comment: This is a dup of a dup of a dup of a dup... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint

Comment: You can use `["1","2"].map(Number)`

Comment: Actually, in addition to being a dupe, this same situation is called out in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case