# what is ['1','2','3'].map(parseInt) result

Tags: javascript

```
['1','2','3'].map(parseInt)
```

return `[1, NaN, NaN]`

I don't know why? In my opinion is like this:

```
['1','2','3'].map(function(i){return parseInt(i,10)})
```

return `[1, 2, 3]`

======================================================
and other
`['1','2','3'].map(parseFloat)`
return `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: look at the map callback arguments - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Check the output of this: `['1', '2', '3'].map(function () { return arguments });`

Comment: I am sure this question has been asked at least 3 times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

The callback function is specified as:

```
callback
Function that produces an element of the new Array, taking three arguments:
currentValue
The current element being processed in the array.
index
The index of the current element being processed in the array.
array
The array map was called upon.
```

Therefore your `map()` function expands into:

```
parseInt('1', 0, the_array) # 1
parseInt('2', 1, the_array) # NaN
parseInt('3', 2, the_array) # NaN
```

Answer (score 10):

You can find answer from Mozilla developers site:

```
// Consider:
["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt);
// While one could expect [1, 2, 3]
// The actual result is [1, NaN, NaN]

// parseInt is often used with one argument, but takes two. The second being the radix
// To the callback function, Array.prototype.map passes 3 arguments: 
// the element, the index, the array
// The third argument is ignored by parseInt, but not the second one,
// hence the possible confusion. See the blog post for more details


function returnInt(element){
  return parseInt(element,10);
}

["1", "2", "3"].map(returnInt);
// Actual result is an array of numbers (as expected)
```

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Also read [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint)

Comment: Your answer is great.But @Howard's easier to understand.So I chose his answer. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @lemon郑 no problem, i glad to help to you))

Comment: This answer is outdated. You can now use `parseFloat` instead of creating a new function.