# Why provide an array argument in Javascript's array.forEach callback?

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

Javascript's array iteration functions (`forEach`, `every`, `some` etc.) allow you to pass three arguments: the current item, the current index and the array being operated on.

My question is: what benefits are there to operating on the array as an argument, vs. accessing it via the closure?

Why should I use this:

```
myArray.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {doSomething(arr);});
```

Instead of this:

```
myArray.forEach(function(item, i) {doSomething(myArray);});
```

Comment: If you want to pass array as argument, why wrap it in `.forEach` in the first place?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible that you want to pass a generic function as an argument to `forEach` and not an anonymous function. Imagine a situation where you have a function defined like that:

```
function my_function(item, i, arr) {
    // do some stuff here
}
```

and then use it on different arrays:

```
arr1.forEach(my_function);
arr2.forEach(my_function);
```

The third argument allows the function to know which array is operating on.

Another case where this might be usefull, is when the array has not been stored in a variable and therefore does not have a name to be referenced with, e.g.:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(item, i, arr) {});
```

Answer (score -2):

there is many cases in real life where knowing where an error is occuring and what was the content of your array. And focusly in a backend JS context like a NodeJS application..

Imagine your website is attacked, you want to know how your pirats are looking to enter into your website, in that case providing the array which contained the entire elements is useful. Look at the ECMASCRIPT 2020 page 642-643 it is written

```
callbackfn is called with three arguments: 
the value of the element,
the index of the element,
and the object being traversed
```

illustration :
[image: callbackfn is called with three arguments: the value of the element, the index of the element, and the object being traversed Ecmascript 2020 manual]

ok try this example

```js
let myArray = [2 , 3, 5 , 7 , "ഊമ്പി", 13]
let foo = null
myArray.forEach(function(value, index, currentObject) {
    try {
        foo = 3.14*value;
        if (Number.isNaN(foo)) throw "foo is NaN" 
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error + ", and value: " + value + ", index: " + index + ", currentObject: " + currentObject);
    }
});
```

Hope that answer will help newbies
That's all folk's !