# Global array object vs foreach() array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between `globalArray` and `foreachArray` object in this below code? and which scenario we need to use the `foreachArray` object instead of `globalArray`?

```js
var globalArray= ['Apple', 'Banana'];


globalArray.forEach(function(item, index, foreachArray) {
  console.log(foreachArray);// result is ['Apple', 'Banana'];
  console.log(globalArray);// result is ['Apple', 'Banana'];
});
```

Comment: The last argument passed in to `forEach()` is the array that's being iterated itself. That's very useful if you want to follow a pure-function approach and not rely on "external" (accessible-via-closure) variables.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters

Comment: I t think they are the same reference.

Comment: @haim770 what you mean by `follow a pure-function approach`??

Comment: @RameshRajendran `['Apple', 'Banana'].forEach`

Comment: @RameshRajendran, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

Comment: @AndrewBone I got it now. Could you please make that as an answer with bit of explanation?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I've added an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `forEach` function accepts 3 [Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters)

> `currentValue` The value of the current element being processed in the array.
>   `index` (*Optional*) The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>   `array` (*Optional*) The array that forEach() is being applied to.

Your question is how is the last parameter connects to the array being iterated through but also why you would want this.

The parameter is actually a reference to the original array

```js
let arrayVar = [0];

arrayVar.forEach((currentValue, index, array) => {
  console.log(arrayVar === array)
})
```

**But why is this useful?** The three main reasons for this are:

- Referencing an array without a variable
- Passing the array to an external function
- Keeping your code tidy and concise

**Reference an Array** that has not been saved as a variable which may come in handy if the array is only going to be used once.

```js
[1,2,3,4].forEach((value,index,array)=>{
  console.log(array);
})
```

**Passing your `forEach` to an external function** this can be incredibly helpful when you want to use the same function on several arrays.

```js
function extFunct(value, index, array) {
  console.log(array)
}

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8];

array.forEach(extFunct);
array2.forEach(extFunct);
```

**Keeping code tidy and concise** you can reference your array without using the long clear array name.

```js
let someLongDescriptiveArrayName = [1,2,3,4];

someLongDescriptiveArrayName.forEach((v,i,a)=>{
  console.log(a)
})
```

I hope that all makes sense, if not feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 3):

They are 2 variable with same reference, only variable names are changed. See below, if I push an item in foreachArray, it add same in globalArray as well.

```js
var globalArray= ['Apple', 'Banana'];


globalArray.forEach(function(item, index, foreachArray) {
  foreachArray.push('Orange');
  console.log(foreachArray);// result is ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'];
  console.log(globalArray);// result is ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'];
});
```

Check here the scenario when should it be used: [Why provide an array argument in Javascript's array.forEach callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528571/why-provide-an-array-argument-in-javascripts-array-foreach-callback)

Comment: guys I also asked `which scenario we need to use?`

Answer (score 2):

They are same(they refer the same object). According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> `array`(In your case foreachArray) is the array that forEach() is being applied to.

This is the signature of `forEach`:

```
someArray.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])
```

Where:

`currentValue`: The value of the current element being processed in the array.

`index(Optional)`: The index of the current element being processed in the array.

`array(Optional)`: The array that forEach() is being applied to.

In your here `someArray` & `array` will be same just like in your case `globalArray` & `foreachArray` are same.

So, if you need to refer the array on which `forEach` is being called use `foreachArray` as it is an language feature provided by JavaScript.

Comment: guys I also asked `which scenario we need to use?`

Answer (score 1):

`globalArray` and `foreachArray` object are the same.

you are passing `foreachArray` as to the third parameter.

> Third parameter `array`: The array that forEach() is being applied to.

And it points the same reference too.

```js
var globalArray= ['Apple', 'Banana'];


globalArray.forEach(function(item, index, foreachArray) {
  foreachArray.push("Cherry");
  console.log("foreachArray: ", foreachArray);// result is ['Apple', 'Banana'];
  console.log("globalArray..", globalArray);// result is ['Apple', 'Banana'];
});
```

Comment: guys I also asked `which scenario we need to use?`

Comment: There is no difference between these two objects. So, you can use any of them. But I prefer to use `foreachArray` as per the documentation.