# JavaScript Array.map(parseInt) causes NaN error

Tags: javascript

When try something like this in JavaScript `['10','10','10'].map(parseInt)`

You will get this is as a result: `[ 10, NaN, 2 ]`

Why does this happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint

Comment: Valid second arguments for `parseInt` is radix parameter from 2-36 (i.e., base 2 to base 36). `map` method of array passes the index as this second argument causing an error for index=1, but apparently not index=0 since that is interpreted as a null or undefined which 'mostly' defaults to base 10 depending on the string prefix ("0" or "0x").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseInt` is often used with *one* argument, but takes *two*.

The first is an expression and the second is the radix.

To the callback function, Array.prototype.map *passes* **3** *arguments* *to* `parseInt`: the element, the index, the array.

The *third* argument is *ignored* by `parseInt`, but not the second one, hence the possible confusion.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35180286/1726544 for a more elaborate answer.