# JavaScript: parseInt's radix mystery with Array.map

Tags: javascript

When I execute the following statements:

```js
var string = "1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1"
console.log(string)
var strings = string.split(" ")
console.log(strings)
var numbers1 = strings.map(parseInt)
console.log(numbers1)
var numbers2 = strings.map(function(i){ return parseInt(i, 10) })
console.log(numbers2)
```

I get the following output in the console:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1"]
[1, NaN, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

I wonder why the second element in `numbers1` is NaN. Why does it work on all the other elements except this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because `map` passes additional arguments.

```
Array.prototype.map = function(currentValue, index, array)
```

So when it is at index 1, it passes 1 as the radix.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) has three arguments that pass to the callback we set as argument:

```
* value
* index
* arr
```

When we check the specifications of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) we can see that parseInt could receive two arguments.

```
* string
* radix
```

The former is the string to be parsed and the latter is the ratio to convert the value.

When we run Snippet 1 code, the following is actually

> > parseInt("1", 0) // 1
>
> > parseInt("1", 1) // NaN
>
> > parseInt("1", 2) // 1
>
> > parseInt("1", 3) // 1

---

You can use [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with `parseInt`

```
array.map(e => parseInt(e, 10));
```

Use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) instead of `parseInt`.

```
arr.map(Number);
```

Or you can also use the anonymous function.

```
arr.map(function(num) {
    return parseInt(num, 10);
});
```