# JavaScript weird result using parseInt

Tags: javascript, parseint

could someone explain why I get this weird result by executing following code?

```
'1.0.0.0'.split('.').map(parseInt);
```

Output:

```
[1, NaN, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint

Answer (score 2):

parseInt has a second argument that is the radix. map is passing three arguments: currentValue, index and the array.
That means that the index of the number is used as the radix.
Try this instead:

```
'1.0.0.0'.split('.').map(function(s) {return parseInt(s);});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qbf7u1d7/

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry for duplicate...

Comment: Alternatively, `'1.0.0.0'.split('.').map(x => parseInt(x))`, if you're working in an environment that supports [ES6 arrow functions](https://www.google.ca/search?q=ES6+arrow+functions&oq=ES6+arrow+functions&aqs=chrome..69i57.1856j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8).