# Javascript: Why does ["2","3"].map(parseInt) return [2, NaN]?

Tags: javascript

Since map callback gets called on each element, I would have expected [2,3] as the return value based on the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Please use the search before asking a new question: [`[javascript] map parseInt`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+map+parseInt)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/262511/1028949

Comment: `map(Number)` is probably what you want.

Comment: This question was discussed recently. The issue is that parseInt takes 2 parameters, expression to evaluate and radix (10 by default).  Change  to ["3","2"].map(parseInt) and receive [11,NaN]

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `.map(Number)` for this type of task:

```
var a = ["2", "3"];

var b = a.map(Number);
```