# Why `(['1','2','3']).map(parseInt)` can't get correct result?

Tags: javascript, mapping

```
(['1','2','3']).map(n => parseInt(n));
```

will return expect result `[1,2,3]`

But:

```
(['1','2','3']).map(parseInt);
```

returns `[1, NaN, NaN]`.

Where is wrong?

Comment: @NagaSaiA – Check the result of `z`

Comment: Always use the explicit version of `map` to avoid unexpected behavior: `[...].map(x => f(x))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does parseInt yield NaN with Array#map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) callback has 3 arguments, second argument is `index` which is causing this result. No matter what `function` you pass as `callback`, this arguments are passed as parameters for that function.

Second argument for [**`parseInt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters) is `radix` hence `parseInt('2',1)` and `parseInt('3',2)` is `NaN`

Execution flow will be:

```js
console.log((['1', '2', '3']).map(function(currenValue, index, array) {
  return parseInt(currenValue, index, array);
}));
```

I will suggest you to go with the `Number`

```js
console.log((['1', '2', '3']).map(Number));
```

Comment: There are some subtle details about `parseInt` here. If you pass a radix of `0` it appears that `parseInt` treat it as base-10 so `0` is the same as `10` or the default. It also appears that radix `1` always return NaN even though base-1 numbers exist (often called a "tally") - so `parseInt` does not support base-1 numbers. Finally at least on Chrome `parseInt` does not support radix higher than 36 - it will always return NaN