# Why can I map Boolean and Number but not RegEx?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Why can we pass `Number`, `Boolean` or `String` to an Array map but not RegExp? Could be something noob, but just trying to get my head around on the basic difference between these constructors?

```js
let array = ["10", "20", "30", "40", "0"];

console.log("Boolean",array.map(Boolean));

console.log("Number",array.map(Number));

console.log("RegExp",array.map(x=>new RegExp(x)));
//cannot do array.map(RegExp)
```

Comment: The one commented out? `array.map(RegExp)` is working?

Comment: what do you expect with it?

Comment: @NinaScholz expected the same output as `array.map(x=>new RegExp(x))` but as Quentin answered, the issue was with `RegExp` having an extra parameter in `constructor`

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript - Array#map and parseInt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/262427/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi Yes the answer is same, but the question was not aware of that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call:

```
array.map(RegExp);
```

You get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor '0'

The function you pass to `map` gets called with more than one argument (`currentValue, index, array`).

`RegExp` (unlike `Boolean` and `Number`) makes use of the second argument (it describes the flags that should be applied to the regex, such as `"g"` for global). A number (which the `index` is) is not a valid flag name.

Comment: Can we conclude that the only way of mapping an array to `RegExp`  is `x=>new RegExp(x))`. Or can there be any other hacky options by just binding second param? Just curious!

Comment: @sabithpocker Yes, you could write a function `function firstArg(fn) { return function(a) { return fn(a); }; }`, then do `array.map(firstArg(RegExp))`.