# Lodash map function unexpected output

Tags: lodash

Using lodash in chrome (latest as of today).

```
_.map("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0".split(":"), parseInt);
```

i get:

```
[0, NaN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Seems like a basic operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - Array#map and parseInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already using Lodash, it's normally safer to replace native methods with Lodash ones when they exist.

In this case, I would use `_.parseInt` instead of just `parseInt`, as the latter may create unexpected results (as is the case here).

The following works as expected:

```
_.map("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0".split(":"), _.parseInt);
```

---

If you're curious as to *why* the 'vanilla' `parseInt` method returns `NaN`, I believe that what is happening is the following:

1. When you use `_.map(collection, iteratee)`, the `iteratee` is actually called with three arguments: `(item, index, collection)`. Source [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.16.6/lodash.js#L653).
2. The problem here is that when you call JavaScript's native `parseInt`, the second argument is a radix that determines which base should be used to parse the integer (binary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal, etc.). Because the iteratee is called with three arguments, this messes up your radix and returns `NaN`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for MDN's explanation on how `parseInt` works.
3. Lodash's `_.parseInt()` avoids that problem by adding a [guard](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.16.6/lodash.js#L14391). It's usually safe to assume that Lodash protects its methods with guards like this to make sure you can use them as iteratees in other Lodash methods.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint/40563484#40563484), your problem can be solved without using lodash this way:

```js
console.log(("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0").split(":").map(Number));
```