# Why does JavaScript's `function.call` have to be called explicitly?

Tags: javascript, prototype, method-call

I have a string, `"  test "`. It's a really ugly string, so let's trim it.

`"  test ".trim()` returns `"test"`. Nice!

Now let's try to do it with that string as an argument.

`String.prototype.trim.call("  test ")` also returns `"test"`. Nice again!

Oh, that means I can use `String.prototype.trim.call` to map an array of ugly strings by their trimmed counterparts, right?

`["  test "].map(String.prototype.trim.call)` does not return `["test"]`.

It throws `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Why is this not allowed?

Comment: `.map(String.prototype.trim.call)` passes the `call` method without the context of `String.prototype.trim`. Try either just a normal arrow function or something similar to `String.prototype.trim.bind(String.prototype)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All function `call` methods are the same function value:

```
> String.prototype.trim.call === Function.prototype.call
true

> String.prototype.trim.call === alert.call
true
```

The function to be called is passed to `Function.prototype.call` as its `this` value. The `this` value for a function call [varies depending on how the call is made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work):

```
f();             // calls f with this === undefined
x.f();           // calls x.f with this === x
x['f']();        // same as previous
f.call(y);       // calls f with this === y
f.apply(y, []);  // same as previous
```

When referencing a function in all cases that *aren’t* calls, there is no `this` value involved.

```
const f = x.f;   // no association with x is maintained
x();             // calls f with this === undefined
```

So, when you pass `String.prototype.trim.call` to `Array#map`, you’re passing the function `Function.prototype.call`, with no relationship to `String.prototype.trim`. `Array#map` then calls it with the `thisArg` [given as the second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) (`undefined`, since you only passed one argument). `Function.prototype.call` calls the `this` value it was given, as it does, and fails because it can’t call `undefined`.

The code is fixable by passing the correct value of `this` as `thisArg`:

```
["  test "].map(String.prototype.trim.call, String.prototype.trim)
```

Pretty verbose, huh? You can abuse the fact that all methods from prototypes are equal to make it shorter (`Set` being a built-in function with a short name):

```
["  test "].map(Set.call, ''.trim)
```

but even that’s no shorter than the usual, readable way:

```
["  test "].map(x => x.trim())
```

which has the bonus of not [forwarding unexpected arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap).