# Is JavaScript map function broken

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript, why does this

```
['10','10','10','10','10'].map(parseInt)
```

Results in this?

```
(5) [10, NaN, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: https://wsvincent.com/javascript-parseint-map/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap

Comment: `['10','10','10','10','10'].map(Number)` thanks to @DanielA.White