# Why is the Observable .map operator defined to require a second parameter in its callback?

Tags: typescript, observable, pointfree

I have a function, in this case I'm using `XLSX.read` this function is defined to take one argument, and a second which may be undef (which is what I want).

Yet, when I try to use this function pointfree in an Rxjs Observable, like this

```
.pipe(
  .map(XLSX.read)
)
```

I get an error.

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(data: any, opts?: ParsingOptions | undefined) => WorkBook' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => WorkBook'.
  Types of parameters 'opts' and 'index' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ParsingOptions | undefined'.
```

Instead what TypeScript wants is,

```
.pipe(
  .map( (x:any) => XLSX.read(x) )
),
```

This is because [Observable.operator.map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) is defined as

```
map<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, R>
```

Why is that map is `(project: (value: T, index: number)` and not `(project: (value: T, index?: number)` with an [optional `index` argument which TypeScript seems to support,](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters)

> In JavaScript, every parameter is optional, and users may leave them off as they see fit. When they do, their value is undefined. **We can get this functionality in TypeScript by adding a `?` to the end of parameters we want to be optional.**

Comment: Could you make this into a [mcve]?  Otherwise I'm not sure where to begin other than to say that `.map()`, whatever it is, probably passes arguments to its callback that you don't expect.

Comment: @jcalz that must be [what's happening here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) Why would map only be defined to take `(value: T, index: number) ` why is the index not optional in that type?

Comment: Index is optional, map accepts a function that takes only one argument, but if the function takes 2 arguments it will receive a number, because that's how map is calling it. In general, there's no way of knowing what will happen inside XLSX.read() when it receives number instead of `ParsingOptions`, so TypeScript protects you from that (using map with parseInt is another in[famous example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap)), and you have to use intermediate function that explicitly  ignores the second argument.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense @artem if you want make that an answer that would be great I think I can use R.unary() as a wrapper to fix this too, (if I wanted the point free solution)