# I don't understand this map() behavior

Tags: javascript

Hi JavaScript masters !

`console.log([ '5', '9', '7' ].map(parseInt))` tells me [5, NaN, NaN]

```
console.log([ '5', '9', '7' ].map(function(element){
    return parseInt(element)
}))
```

tells me [5, 9, 7]

But why ? ^^'

Comment: Hi, could you please give some more information?

Comment: `console.log([ '5', '9', '7' ].map(Number))` tells me [5, 9, 7] ...

Comment: Thank you @Jiří the answer is there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap

Comment: [Tricky use case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case)

Comment: should be `console.log([ '5', '9', '7' ].map(x => parseInt(x)));`

Comment: If you read the MDN documentation, *every* example until the "Tricky use case" that is this exact problem is using an anonymous function to do the work.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because, as it is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> **parseInt is often used with one argument, but takes two**. The first is
> an expression and the second is the radix to the callback function,
> Array.prototype.map passes 3 arguments:
>
> - the element
> - the index
> - the array
>
> The third argument is ignored by parseInt, but not the second one,
> hence the possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`map` calls the function you give it with 3 parameters: the value, the index of it in the array, and the array itself. Your second approach safely ignores these, but your first one causes the second parameter to be interpreted as the base of the number, which isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Best explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/262511/6935763

No use of copying pasting here the whole answer

Comment: Posting a link isn't very useful either. Just cast a duplicate vote.

Comment: um...i did? You can see my name there who marked it duplicated! I just posted as an answer for anyone who scrolls down looking for answer here anyway