# Recursive function that flattens an object within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, flatten

So I have an array of objects that I receive like this:

```
[
  {
    accountName: {
      type: 'link',
      value: {
        value: '1234567890123456789',
        to: '/q?Id=1237896540789654',
      },
    },
    bank: {
      type: 'text',
      value: 'Foo Bank',
    },
  },
  {
    accountName: {
      type: 'link',
      value: {
        value: '9234567890123456789',
        to: '/q?Id=9234567890123456789',
      },
    },
    bank: {
      type: 'text',
      value: 'Foo Bank',
    },
  },
];
```

And I need an output like this:

```
[
  {
    accountName: '1234567890123456789', 
    bank: 'Foo Bank'
  },
  {
    accountName: '9234567890123456789', 
    bank: 'Foo Bank'
  }
]
```

How could I resolve it?
The array of objects doesn't always have the same shape so I need a recursive function that holds the first key from the original object and flatten the value until it is no more an object.

Comment: Thought this was a python question and did it here. 

https://trinket.io/python/609679e8d9

oops. But maybe it'll be useful to someone

Comment: Could you give us an example where there is nesting so we can see what you mean by different shape?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of libraries that might help, but maybe something like this would work?

```
results.map(result => ({
    accountName: result.accountName.value.value,
    bank: result.bank.value
}));
```

Except that you said "The array of objects doesn't always have the same shape", but I'm not sure how to address that. You said something about searching recursively, does this mean looking for the deepest "value" in the object?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the "deepest" value
Also the properties in the output have to be named accordingly as the original properties. It doesn't always have the same properties.

Comment: @Kauyumari [Code Maniac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613459/675721) looks pretty good to me. [IceMetalPunk's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613381/675721) is good, too, but the complexity is higher. Don't forget to accept if one of them answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

This code should iteratively pull out the deepest value of each key in each object:

```
const processed = data.reduce((result, obj) => {
  return result.concat(Object.keys(obj).reduce((entry, key) => {
      entry[key] = obj[key];
      while (entry[key].value) { entry[key] = entry[key].value; }
      return entry;
    }, {}));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, check if the `value` is an object or not, if it's object go to deeper level else use the value

```js
let data = [{accountName: {type: 'link',value: {value: '1234567890123456789',to: '/q?Id=1237896540789654',},},bank: {type: 'text',value: 'Foo Bank',},},{accountName: {type: 'link',value: {value: '9234567890123456789',to: '/q?Id=9234567890123456789',},},bank: {type: 'text',value: 'Foo Bank',},},];

let getDeepestValue = obj => {
  let value = obj.value
  while(typeof value == 'object'){
    value = value.value 
  }
  return value
}

let final = data.map(({accountName,bank})=>{
  return{
    accountName: getDeepestValue(accountName),
    bank: getDeepestValue(bank)
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: I like this one better than IceMetalPunk's answer, I find it more readable.

Comment: Nice, but see my answer for a recursive alternative to `getDeepestValue`.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a version like this:

```js
// helper functions
const mapObject = (fn) => (o) => Object .fromEntries (
  Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k, fn (v)])
)
const map = (fn) => (xs) => xs .map(x => fn (x))

// main functions
const deepestValue = (o) => 
  typeof o .value== "object" ? deepestValue (o .value) : o .value

const transform = map (mapObject (deepestValue))

// demo
const input=[{accountName: {type: "link", value: {value: "1234567890123456789", to: "/q?Id=1237896540789654"}}, bank: {type: "text", value: "Foo Bank"}}, {accountName: {type: "link", value: {value: "9234567890123456789", to: "/q?Id=9234567890123456789"}}, bank: {type: "text", value: "Foo Bank"}}]

console.log (transform (input))
```

We can build this in a step-by-step manner:

We start by writing a simple recursive `deepestValue` function like this:

```js
const deepestValue = (o) => 
  typeof o .value== "object" ? deepestValue (o .value) : o .value
```

That could be used to write our transformation function this way:

```js
const transform = (xs) => xs .map (x => Object.fromEntries (
  Object .entries (x) .map (([k, v]) => [k, deepestValue (v)])
))
```

(If your environment [does not support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_object_fromentries) the relatively new [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), it's quite easy to shim.)

We could stop there.  But it's worth noting that this `entries`->`map`->`fromEntries` dance is a very reusable pattern.  It's basically mapping a function over the properties of an object.  Perhaps a good name is `mapObject`.  We can simply extract that and use it like this:

```js
const mapObject = (fn) => (o) => Object .fromEntries (
  Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k, fn (v)])
)

const transform = (xs) => xs .map (mapObject (deepestValue))
```

But there is another function we might want to abstract out of this, a `map` function that works like `Array.prototype.map` but which is a stand-alone function.  That is also very easy to write.

```
const map = (fn) => (xs) => xs .map (x => fn (x))
```

(I don't write simply `(fn) => (xs) => xs .map (fn)` for reasons described many places, including in [Why does parseInt yield NaN with Array#map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427).)

With this, we can now write the snippet above.

Functions such as `map` and `mapObject` can go in our personal utility libraries to be reused in various places in our application.  Libraries such as [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/) or [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author) collect such things into useful collections.  Ramda's [`map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) actually covers both these cases, so in Ramda we might write `const transform = map (map (deepestValue))`.

Note that I would not extract these helper functions on the basis of single cases.  If I'd never seen the pattern before, I would be perfectly happy with the first version of `transform`.  But I've done similar things often enough that this abstraction makes sense to me.  And I think it always helps to break things down into really simple pieces.