# Confusion with how thenable callback works in Promise?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning promises. The code excerpt I want to show is this

```
promisedFunction.then(data=>console.log(data))
```

or simply

```
promisedFunction.then(console.log)
```

which is equivalent of the former code excerpt. The question is how is that possible to just use `then(console.log)` instead of `then(data=>console.log(data))`? Does it mean that we can omit the passed-from-promise data in thenable callback?

Comment: You can use that when the number of arguments is the same.

Answer (score 3):

`data=>console.log(data)` is a function that takes a parameter and calls a method with the passed in argument.

If you pass `console.log` it will execute the same method and still pass the same argument.

In effect you are dropping the extra function call - slightly more abstractly, imagine this:

```js
//some function `f`
const f = x => x + 1;

//different function `g` that just forwards the call to `f`:
const g = x => f(x);

console.log(g(41)); //42
```

The definition of `g` is just a function that *all it does* is call `f`. Which has exactly the same effect as the `f` function. So, we can just re-write it as:

```js
//some function `f`
const f = x => x + 1;

//different function `g` that just forwards the call to `f`:
const g = f;

console.log(g(41)); //42
```

and get *exactly* the same effect.

In Lambda Calculus, this removal of an essentially empty "wrapper function" is called [Eta reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction).

Therefore, yes, both `.then(data => console.log(data))` and `.then(console.log)` do exactly the same, you're performing the same sort of conversion where you're taking out a dummy forwarding function.

---

However, that's not *always* an option. For example, if removing the forwarding function will end up calling the target with *more* parameters, you can get different behaviour. An infamous example is [`parseInt` when used in `.map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap):

```js
const arrayOfString = ["1", "2", "3"];

const arrayOfIntegers1 = arrayOfString.map(parseInt);
const arrayOfIntegers2 = arrayOfString.map(x => parseInt(x));

console.log("arrayOfIntegers1", arrayOfIntegers1);
console.log("arrayOfIntegers2", arrayOfIntegers2);
```

The issue is that `Array#map` calls the callback with *three* parameters - the item, the index, and the array. And `parseInt` has an optional second parameter - if passed in, it changes how the number is parsed. So you get `NaN`.

The easiest way to observe this is with `console.log`:

```js
const arrayOfString = ["1", "2", "3"];

console.log(" --- using just `console.log` as callback ---");
arrayOfString.map(console.log);

console.log(" --- using just `x => console.log(x)` as callback ---");
const arrayOfIntegers2 = arrayOfString.map(x => console.log(x));
```

So, dropping the intermediate function works as long as it has the same [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) as what it will be called with and what the next function will be called with.

Answer (score 1):

`data => console.log(data)` is a function which takes in `data` and then calls the function `console.log` with `data` as its argument. So, it's a function which gets given `data` and then it gives that exact same `data` argument to the `console.log` function.

As you know `console.log` is a function, so, you can place `console.log` instead of your arrow function. This way, it will be called with the `data` argument and any other arguments natively passed into `.then()`'s [*onFulfilled*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Parameters) callback (in this case it only gets given the resolved value of the promise).

Take the following example below. `bar` gets given `"hello"`, which it gives to `foo`, `foo` accepts `"hello"` and returns `"hello"` back to where it was called, so, `bar` ends up returning `"hello"`:

```js
const foo = x => x;
const bar = x => foo(x); 

console.log(bar("hello"));
```

In the above example, `bar` acts somewhat like a middle-man, as all it does is pass `x` to `foo`. This middle-step can be removed, by straight-up assigning `bar` to `foo`. This way, when we call `bar()`, we are executing the code defined within the function `foo`. This is the same idea that allows you to remove the need to explicitly defined your arrow function in `.then()`:

```js
const foo = x => x;
const bar = foo; 

console.log(bar("hello"));
```

This style of coding is known as [point-free style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) code and, in this case, is achieved by eta-reduction.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of promise or the "resolved value" is the input to callback passed in then.
This behavior is not specific to promise but even `[1,2,3].forEach(console.log)` behaves the same where the 3 arguments of forEach are passed to console log. Thus you get ,

```
1 0 Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]

2 1 Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]

3 2 Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`promisedFunction.then` expects a function to which will receive the data as a parameter.

in the case of `data=>console.log(data)` is an array function equal to:

```
function(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

and `console.log` is also a function which prints in console what receives as a parameter.

That's why console.log works.

If you had:

```
var print = function(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

`promisedFunction.then(print)` would also work.

See this working example that will resolve after 2 secs:

```js
const doSomething = function(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let wait = setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Promise resolved!');
  }, 2000)
  })
};

var print = function(data) {
   console.log(data);
}

doSomething().then(print)
```