# addEventListener('event', callback) vs addEventListener('event', function() { callback() })

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I wonder there is a difference between...

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { callback() });
```

and

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
```

I've seen code like this, and I'm curious as to why they put the function inside an anonymous function.

```js
var on_load = function(f) {
  if (document.body === null)
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { f() }, false)
  else
    f()
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59878788

Comment: Whenever you have function(...args) { fn(...args) }, as a parameter of other function, just provide fn. It will be working fine in both cases, but do it "right way"

Comment: Does that mean that `addEventListener('event', callback)` is more recommended than `addEventListener('event', function() { callback() })`?

Comment: @YiJisol *in this case* it's the same and this it can be eta-reduced. Whether it's "more recommended" is opinion-based. I'd use the first version myself. Others might prefer the latter, as it's easier to refactor to add parameters to it. Many probably wouldn't care.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear difference. This first example is pretty useless, because the callback function is being deprived of the event argument:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { callback() });
```

whereas this one:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
```

provided that the value of callback is a function, will be called with the event as the first argument and with the element whose event handler is handling the event, as the this-argument.

So if you had asked what is the difference between:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { callback.apply(this, arguments) });
```

versus this one:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
```

then the answer is: nothing but one extra indirection.