# Need to understand inline function call with react FC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im quite new to React and have created a new view at my company.
I use inline functions because many guides do the same.
Everything is written as function components.

I write onClick like this:

```
onClick: () => onBackClick()
```

My co-workes says this is a usless arrow function.

Will try to give you the whole picture.
Parent component has the onBackClick function declared

```
const Parent = () => {
     const onBackClick = () => {backOff}
    
          <Child {...{onBackClick}}/>

}

const Child = ({onBackClick}) => {
 return (
   <MyButton {...{onClick: () => onBackClick() }}/>
)
```

}

My co-workers want me to write it like this:

```
onClick: onBackClick
```

I dont get a good explanation on why and really would like to learn.
Can someone be kind to explain why this is a better way to write it.

Regards.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59878788

Comment: Thx, that was a great explenation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare:

```js
const onBackClick = () => { console.log("This does something useful"); };

const onClick = onBackClick;

onClick();
```

```js
const onBackClick = () => { console.log("This does something useful"); };

const onClick = () => onBackClick();

onClick();
```

In the first example (your co-worker's way) there is one function and it is passed around.

In the second example (your way) you create a whole new function that does nothing except call the first function.

---

Aside from being redundant, this creates an extra inefficiency in React.

When the component is re-rendered, the output is checked for changes.

`onBackClick` might not have changed, but (when using your way) `onClick` has, so React will delete the old event handler from the DOM and assign a new one with the new (but identical) `onClick` function you created.