# Understanding of functional reduction

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

There are a few examples in this [functional programing book](https://mostly-adequate.gitbook.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch02#:%7E:text=The%20world%20is,1) about equivalency between different functions. For example, if my understanding is correct it means:

```
func(param => otherFunc(param))
func(otherFunc)                   // simplified
```

And, if I can articulate it in words to the best of my ability, I would say:

> A function that takes a certain number of parameters and then only
> returns a second function called with those parameters as arguments
> is the same as a function that just takes the second function as a single parameter.

Is this a correct understanding? What would be some examples that would show how this would work? The only ones I can think of myself so far are quite trivial, so I'd like to see if I can see more examples to deepen my understanding of some applications of this.

Comment: I discuss this concept [in this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59878788). The context is a bit more concrete (using this kind of reduction in `.then()`) but the explanation should cover a lot of of the generic case.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that func = otherFunc ?

Comment: @ITgoldman no, it means `param => otherFunc(param)` is the same as `otherFunc`

Comment: You have to be careful when doing these transformations in JavaScript. In some cases `func()` passes extra arguments that usually get ignored, and `otherFunc()` has additional optional arguments. When you put these two things together, you get unexpected results. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap

Comment: Your example doesn't "return a second function". It actually calls the second function and returns the result. This is equivalent to just the second function. You have to be very careful with terminology when discussing first-class functions.

Comment: @Barmar yes, the equality holds if the arity is the same in both cases. Otherwise, there is not guarantee that it would work the same. Chances are it wouldn't.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [cs.se].

Comment: I'm really surprised that the book doesn't give the name of this technique (which would allow you to research the topic better). It's [η-reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_reduction).

Comment: @Bergi would you want to show an example of how the eta reduction works on the above javascript example?

Comment: @David542 the example *is* eta reduction. It's when you convert `x => f(x)` into just `f` to peel off the useless wrapper function.

Comment: @David542 Not sure what you mean. You've already shown an example yourself?

Comment: @Bergi sure but how would my javascript example translate into the more mathematical notation used in lambda calculus for the eta reduction? that's the part I don't understand.

Comment: @David542 `func(otherFunc)` is function application, in lambda calculus often `func otherFunc` (but that doesn't make it easier for newcomers). And the JS `func(param => otherFunc(param))` can be written in lambda calculus as `func (λparam . otherFunc param)`. The point being that `λparam . otherFunc param` = `otherFunc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the lambda calculus, which is the foundation for a lot of functional programming concepts, this is called Eta reduction and is one of the few fundamental reduction operations in the system.

*η-Reduction* 
LC: `λx.f x = f` 
Javascript: `(x => f(x)) = f`

It is quite trivial to prove to yourself that this works. "Wrapping" the function in a lambda just explicitly provides the next argument which is applied anyway.

For the sake of brevity assume we have an increment function INC and LC numbers in the church encoding. 
LC: `(λx.INC x) 3 -> INC 3 -> 4` = `INC 3 -> 4`
Javascript: `(x => INC(x))(3) -> INC(3) -> 4` = `INC(3) -> 4`

This breaks down a little bit if you have a multi-argument function. Since pure lambda calculus only has unary functions, eta reduction is this simple, but in JS we can use a trick to capture any number of arguments.

JS "Eta" Equvilancy 
`((...x) => f(...x)) = f`

As for applications, you can use this fact to simplify expressions. Other than that there isn't really a reason to expand expressions this way, only reducing them for sake of performance and readability.

Yes, these are equivalent, and this is actually a core functional programming principle that you have discovered.

Comment: could you explain a bit more about how this part is reduced: `λx.fx = f`. I'm sure it's "trivial", but could you just show a step-by-step with the lambda calculus?

Comment: lambda-calculus has three reduction operations. \
-conversion - `λx.fx = λy.fy`,
β-reduction (application) - `(λx.fx)2 = f2` ,
η-reduction - `λx.fx = f`.

So it's not so much a consequence of other steps as it is a "step" itself. However, by applying beta reduction you can see that eta reduction holds true.
`(λx.INCx)3 -> INC3 -> 4 = INC3 -> 4`. Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#reduction

Comment: Just to expand a bit on what @EricBreyer said: alpha reduction is simply renaming. In terms of JS that is like doing `f = x => x + 1` to `f = num => num + 1`. They are equivalent, only the parameter name is changed. Beta reduction would be inlining the parameter with the value for it. If you have `(num => num + 1)(2)` that calls the function with the value `2` which can be re-written to `2 + 1` by substituting `num`. And eta reduction is just removing wrapper functions: `x => isNaN(x)` to `isNaN`. Beta reduction can show it clearly `(x => isNaN(x))(anyValue)` is same as `isNaN(anyValue)` .

Comment: Of course there is a reason to expand expressions that way, which is to delay their evaluation until the actual application, turning `f(x)` into `(y => f(x)(y))`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to do my best explanation by step by step examples.

### Step 1

> Function definition

In javacript you can define a function with 2 different syntax

```js
function inc(number) {
  return number + 1
}
```

or

```js
const inc = (number) {
  return number + 1
}

// or simplifed

const inc = (number) => number + 1
```

Those 2 syntax are more or less equivalent but the second one is stays that you have a constant called inc (so a variable) that have a pointer to a piece of memory that contains a function.

So, `inc` is a variable that contains (as value) the function payload.

### Step 2

> This step is not related with the previous one

Supposing that we have an array and we want to increment each element into a new array we can use the function map.

Map is a function that creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

[Mozilla Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const result = [1,2,3,4].map((number) => number + 1)
console.log(result)
```

### Step 3

> Let's make ingredients together

We have have a `inc` function and we want to use that function in our `map`.

We can do a very simple things.

```js
const inc = (x) => x + 1

const result = [1,2,3,4].map(number => inc (number))
console.log(result)
```

### Step 4

> Let's try another approach.

Forget for a moment what we have done on step 3, trying using our `inc` function. We will try another approac.

At step 1 we have seen that a function is defined as follows.

```js
const inc = (number) => number + 1
```

The semantics around the equal sign is quite powerful and is saying:

> the expression `inc`
>
> is equivalent to
>
> the expression `(number) => number + 1`

We can take our `inc` function definition and the Step 2 code.

```js
const inc = (number) => number + 1
const result = [1,2,3,4].map((number) => number + 1)
```

On the right side of both lines we have a duplicated expression:

```js
(number) => number + 1
```

And first line says that an equivalent expression is `inc`. Trying to apply this approach the results is:

```js
const inc = (x) => x + 1
const result = [1,2,3,4].map(inc)
console.log(result)
```

when you are trying to read a code written in this way you can imagine to inline `inc` label with its own expression.

### Bonus

> Let's apply the approach with more than 1 parameter

Trying to apply this approach for 2 parameter function we need another usecase. Given an array of numbers we want the sum of each number.

To achieve that we'll use the standard `reduce` function.

[Mozilla Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const result = [1,2,3,4].reduce((a, x) => a + x, 0)
console.log(result)
```

now we can extract a sum function and replace the expression with it's label.

```js
const sum = (a, b) => a + b
const result = [1,2,3,4].reduce(sum, 0)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

These two

```js
func(param => otherFunc(param))
func(otherFunc)
```

are not exactly the same, the reason being that *these* two are not exactly the same

```js
f1 = param => otherFunc(param)
f2 = otherFunc
```

Indeed look at this example:

```js
// silly function taking two args and producing a string
function f(x,y) {
    return "<" + x + ',' + y + ">";
}

f1 = f;
f2 = x => f(x);

console.log(f1(2,3)); // ok
console.log(f2(2,3)); // not ok!
```

The reason they are not the same is that `x => f(x)` is a function that only takes 1 argument, even though the function `f` expects 2, so when you feed `f2` with 2 arguments, it ingnores the second argument, and then calls `f` with 1 argument only, which results in the second argument (of `f`) being `undefined`.

Clearly, you could have written `f2` as `(x, y) => f(x, y)`, but then you'd be in trouble if `f` was ternary.

So, if you don't want to spell out all the arguments of the wrapper function to make it agree with `f`, you have to write the wrapper function like this

```js
f2correct = (...x) => f(...x);
```

which expresses the idea that `f2correct` can take any number of arguments, and it forwards them all to `f`. In fact, `f2correct` is equivalent to `f`.

As regards your understanding of that, I think you got close, but probably misworded it.

> A function that takes a certain number of parameters and then only returns a second function called with those parameters as arguments is the same as <s>a function that just takes the second function as a single parameter</s> the second function.

Comment: Eta reduction leads to the same result when the arity is the same, e.g. `(x) => f(x)` for `f` being unary and `(x, y) => g(x, y)` for `g` being binary. Or also if the function is treated as the same arity as the wrapper: `Promise.resolve("3.14").then(x => parseInt(x))` is the same as doing `.then(parseInt)` while the infamous `["1.14", "2.14", "3.14"].map(parseInt)` isn't the same as `.map(x => parseInt(x))`. So yes, while in the most general case removing the wrapper function is not the same, in *a lot* of cases, eta reduction does apply. Helps that FP doesn't tend to use variadic functions.

Comment: @VLAZ, I've better clarfied that my suggestion of using `(...x) => f(...x)` was aiming at the general that you don't know how many arguments `f` takes. But thanks for the comment. As regards FP tending not to use variadic functions, Haskell doesn't indeed, but Clojure does have and, as far as I've understood, use them exensively.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably "easier" (YMMV) to see when you evaluate expressions.

Let's start with something simple:

```js
42 === (40 + 1 + 1); // true
42 === (40 + 2);     // true
42 === (42);         // true
42 === 42;           // true
```

Let's define `inc` and evaluate it:

```js
const inc = x => x + 1;

inc === (inc); // true
inc === inc;   // true
```

And so:

```js
inc(41) === (inc)(41); // true
inc(41) === inc(41);   // true
```

Important bit is here: `(inc)`.

The expression evaluates the function and simply returns it. So when you do `(inc)(41)` you end up doing `inc(41)`.

Let's inline `inc` in the right operand:

```js
inc(41) === (x => x + 1)(41); // true
//           ^^^^^^^^^^
//           i.e. inc
```

Now let's add an unnecessary wrapper:

```js
   inc(41) === (n => (x => x + 1)(n))(41); // true
//              ^     ^           ^   ^^
//              |     |           |   |
//              |     +<<<<<<<<<<<+   |
//              |                 |   |
//              +>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+   |
//              |                     |
//              +<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+
```

Let's simplify a little bit:

```js
   inc(41) === (n => inc(n))(41); // true
//              ^        ^   ^^
//              |        |   |
//              |        |   |
//              +>>>>>>>>+   |
//              |            |
//              +<<<<<<<<<<<<+
```

Or just:

```js
inc(41) === (inc)(41); // true
```

It also helps to know how to read things:

```
(n => inc(n))(41)
```

The expression `n => inc(n)` (which is a function) is *applied* to `41`. (At this point `n` is equal to `41`.) Then `inc` is applied to `n`.

So you might as well just apply `inc` to `41` directly and skip the first expression, i.e.:

```js
(n => inc(n))(41) === inc(41); // true
```

Comment: It's not clear what the intended difference between `inc` and `(inc)` is (or between `42` and `(42)`)

Comment: There's none. In my initial example I've used them to reduce expressions and show that they are equal notations by having them both standing on each side of a `===` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript if you don't use parenthesis, you just get back a function (pointer).

Look at the difference between.

```
var a = func(x);
var b = func;
```

The first call executes the function `func` and returns the result and saves it into `a`.

The second call (without the parenthesis) returns the function as-is, and just binds it to `b`. After this, doing a.

```
var c = b(x)
```

should be the same as `a`, as long there are no side-effects.

Now look at the lambda-function.

```
var d = param => func(param);
```

Here you just create a function `d` that calls `func` and passes it arguments along to `func`.

You btw. also can write it this way.

```
var d = function(param) { return func(param) }
```

and this piece of code can be re-written.

```
function d(param) {
    return func(param);
}
```

as you now maybe see. `d` is the same as `func`. And again to the loop, this piece of code can be re-written.

```
var d = func;
```

Both function are the same.

That's why you can pass `otherFunc` in your example directly. You just pass the function as-is, without the need to create another new function.