# split an array without separate number of two digits

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following variable with some number.

```
const string = "5,5,5,5";
const string = "5,5,5,5,10";
```

I pasted it twice to explain what I am trying to do.

I want to add all the numbers and get a total.

The first I did, is cleaning the variable to avoid the commas, when I split it

```
let stringWithoutSigns = string.replace(/,/g, "");
```

I paste the full code to better understanding.

```js
const string = "5,5,5,5";

let stringWithoutSigns = string.replace(/,/g, "");

let itemString = stringWithoutSigns.length;

if (itemString > 2) {
  result = cleanString();
  console.log(result)
}

function cleanString() {
  let arrString = stringWithoutSigns.split("").map(function(index) {
    return parseInt(index, 10);
  });
  console.log(arrString);
  let sum = arrString.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  return sum;
}
```

My problem, is that if I type a new number like 10, it doesn't works, because is splitted into 1, 0

Comment: Why are you removing the commas? Use `string.split(',')` to split the original string at the commas.

Comment: isn't just: `var sum = string.split(",").reduce((a,b) => +a + +b)`?

Comment: @CalvinNunes You need to use `parseInt()`

Comment: maybe `var sum = string.split(",").reduce((a,b) => (+a)+(+b))`

Comment: if I don´t removed them, when I asplit it, I will have something like this ["5", ","...]

Comment: Don't split it twice.

Comment: @CalvinNunes I going to tyr

Comment: @Barmar - you don't need parseInt - calvin's code is correct

Comment: @Barmar unary operator does the same than `parseInt()`

Comment: ahashasdfa%$&$$... Thanks @CalvinNunes I was going on the bad way.... ahhh

Comment: @CalvinNunes your answer was the correct one Thanks a millions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the commas, use them to split the string into numbers.

```js
const string = "5,5,5,5";

result = cleanString(string);
console.log(result)


function cleanString(string) {
  let arrString = string.split(",").map(function(num) {
    return parseInt(num, 10);
  });
  console.log(arrString);
  let sum = arrString.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Or `.map(Number)`

Comment: @Cid No, because `map()` sends 3 arguments to the callback, and parseInt uses the second argument as the radix.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap

Comment: @Barmar true about `parseInt`, I was sure the default value for radix was 10, but docs told me something else

Comment: @Cid The problem is that the argument passed by `map()` overrides the default.

Answer (score 1):

Split the `string` by checking `,` rather that on empty string. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
const string = "5,5,5,10";

let stringWithoutSigns = string.replace(/,/g, "");

let itemString = stringWithoutSigns.length;

if (itemString > 2) {
result = cleanString();
console.log(result)
}

function cleanString() {
  let arrString = string.split(",").map(function(index) {
    return parseInt(index, 10);
  });
  console.log(arrString);
  let sum = arrString.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I let one answer more. I can pass an empty string, 0, or as may numbers as I want(I tested it with 20 numbers untill now)

```js
const string = "5,5,5,5,10"

console.log(add(string))

function add(string) {
  let splitted = string.split(",");
  let numbers = splitted.map(value => Number(value || 0));
  return numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic

```
string.split(',').reduce((num,acc)=> parseInt(num) + parseInt(acc) )
```