# Shortcut of calling a method without writing parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, loops, ecmascript-6

Following is the code in which I need some clarification. I was expecting this code to console `'mango', 'apple', 'orange'` one by one similar to **Option 2** but this is throwing another input which I am not getting how JavaScript is spitting this output.

```js
const myFunc = (...data) => (data.map(console.log))

myFunc('mango', 'apple', 'orange')
```

**Option 2 - (Expected Output)**

```js
var myFunc = (...data) => {
  data.map(x => {
    console.log(x)
  })
}

myFunc('mango', 'apple', 'orange')
```

Correct my understanding with this please, as I was thinking that `data.map(console.log)` will log the items only.

Comment: `console.log` takes more than one parameter.

Comment: Because it is `console.log(currentValue, index, array)`

Comment: Not an exact dupe but similar enough to be of interest: [Why does parseInt yield NaN with Array#map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/262427)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Your code works fine, and should produce the expected result for other functions.

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) accepts a callback function, which it will call for each element of the array. MDN:

> The callback function accepts the following arguments:
>
> `currentValue`
> The current element being processed in the array.
>
> `indexOptional`
> The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>
> `arrayOptional`
> The array map was called upon.

Because you're passing `console.log` as the callback function, you're effectively writing this:

```js
const myFunc = (...data) => (data.map((curVal,index,arr) => console.log(curVal,index,arr)))

myFunc('mango', 'apple', 'orange')
```

So the extra output is because you're also logging the `index` and `array` parameters unknowingly.

Just be aware that any other function you use will also receive these extra parameters. If they only accept one parameter, then it should work exactly as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

`console.log` takes more than one parameter.

You could wrap your function in another function and use only the first parameter.

<sub>`forEach` is better if the result of `map` is never used.</sub>

```js
const single = fn => first => fn(first);

var myFunc = (...data) => {
    data.forEach(single(console.log));
}

myFunc('mango', 'apple', 'orange')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the best practices :) +1

Comment: A quick query, is it advisable to use spread operator to accept multiple parameters or we should avoid this approach ?

Comment: @Nesh, it depends ... sorry.

Comment: @Nesh, when used in a parameter list it is a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). This is a language feature and you should definitely use it if your goal is to accept a totally arbitrary number of parameters. If you know the number of parameters, they should be specified explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what `map` does under the hood:

```js
function map(a, f) {
  var b = new Array(a.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b[i] = f(a[i], i, a);
  }
  return b;
}

console.log(
  map([0, 1, 2, 3], function(x, i, a) {
    return x * x;
  })
);
```

As you can see, `f` receives 3 parameters: the element `a[i]`, its position `i`, and the array `a`. It's up to you to use them or not, as shown in these twisted examples:

```js
console.log(
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"].map(function(x, i, a) {
    return x + " " + a[(i + 1) % a.length];
  })
);

console.log(
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"].map(function(_, i) {
    return "2^" + i + " = " + 2 ** i;
  })
);
```

Since `console.log` takes any number of parameters, if you pass it directly to `map` it will use all of the three parameters `a[i]`, `i` and `a`. To pick only one parameter you need a filter:

```js
"abcd".split("").map(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

However, as Nina said, `forEach` is more appropriate in this case since we ignore the output of `map` (which is `[undefined × 4]`):

```js
"abcd".split("").forEach(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The output in **Option 1** will be :-

```
mango 0 (3) ["mango", "apple", "orange"]
apple 1 (3) ["mango", "apple", "orange"]
orange 2 (3) ["mango", "apple", "orange"]
```

This is because of below 2 reasons:-

The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element.
The **map()** method calls the provided function once for each element in an array, in order.