# Why is it that passing parseInt into array.map doesn't work, but (x => parseInt(x)) does?

Tags: javascript

```
['1', '4', '9', '16'].map(parseInt)
```

gives

```
[1, NaN, NaN, 1]
```

But

```
['1', '4', '9', '16'].map(x => parseInt(x))
```

gives

```
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Why?

Comment: Because `parseInt` accept TWO arguments but the second one is optional and array.map will pass THREE arguments to `parseInt`. So basically you have incompatible understanding of arguments. `parseInt` expects `parseInt(string, base)` eg if you want to parse a hex number like `3a` or `ff` you can do `parseInt("ff", 16)`. **BUT** `array.map()` will pass you `(item, index, array) => {}` so the first item you will get `parseInt('1', 0)` which I assume will be interpreted as base-10 number because base-0 makes no sense, then `parseInt('4', 1)` which is a base-1 number. Base-1 is weird but exists..

Comment: ... then `parseInt('9', 2)` which is a binary number like `1011001` or `111001` so the digit '9' is not a valid binary digit. Then finally `parseInt('16', 3)` which is a base-3 number. The digit '6' is not a valid base-3 number. Base-3 numbers are like '10012210102'. So in this case `parseInt` treats '6' as a non-number character. It works the same as `parseInt('5hello')` which returns '5'. In this case it treats it like `parseInt('1K',3)` so it returns 1

Comment: See the answers to similar question. Put simply the map method will pass 3 arguments to the function it is passed by default. only by explicitly using the first argument can you stop the other two arguments being passed to parseInt and confusing it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap as this gives a good answer.