# How to count the number of occurances in an array and translate it into an array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, reduce, multiple-occurrence

I am trying to take in an array of names (with duplicates) and output a array of objects.

Input: single array

```js
const arr = ['M', 'M', 'M', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'C', 'S', 'S', 'S']
```

Output: array of objects

```js
[
  {
    name: 'M'
    duplicates: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'S'
    duplicates: 6
  }...
]
```

I have tried this solution, but this is giving me the name of each array item for the key name. That is not what I want.

This is my current code:

```js
const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] ??
        (acc[curr] = {
            [curr]: 0,
        })
    acc[curr][curr]++
    return acc
}, [])
console.log(result)

/*output:
[
  C: {C: 1}
  M: {M: 3}
  R: {R: 1}
  S: {S: 6}
]
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index the accumulator by the element, increment counts for matching keys, strip out the index (with Object.values) at the end...

```js
const arr = ['M', 'M', 'M', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'C', 'S', 'S', 'S'];

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(el)) acc[el] = { name: el, duplicates: 0 };
  acc[el].duplicates++;
  return acc;
}, {}));


console.log(result)
```

Comment: how about `const arr = ['toString', 'toString', 'valueOf']`

Comment: @georg - modified to restrict acc to its own keys.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to discuss a harder way to do this.

Yes, that's right, **harder**!  But that's only if you're building this up from scratch.  If you already have a library of utility functions, it could be much simpler.

We will end up writing a transformation function that looks like this:

```js
const transform = pipe (
  countBy (identity),
  Object .entries,
  map (zipObj (['name', 'duplicates']))
)
```

The idea is that with a number of small utility functions, we can write such a function in a simpler, declarative manner, describing it as a set of transformations.

Below we start building our own list of utility functions.  These ones are modelled after functions from [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author) but we write our own versions here.  Our functions will be simpler than those in Ramda, and somewhat less powerful.  But they will cover a great number of use-cases and are simple to extend.

### Step 1: `count`

The first thing we want to do is to count the elements by key.

We want to take

```js
['M', 'M', 'M', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'C', 'S', 'S', 'S']
```

and covert it into

```js
{M: 3, S: 6, R: 1, C: 1}
```

We can write this function as a simple reduction over our values, like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
const count = (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => ((a [x] = (a [x] || 0) + 1), a), Object .create (null))
```

We could stop there, but it's really easy to see some useful extensions to this.  Perhaps we don't care about case, and want to count all the lowercase `m`s together with the uppercase `M`s.  Or we have a list of people with their birthdays, and we want to count them by birth year.  Or any of a number of scenarios.  If we extended that function to also take a transformation function, we could cover all these at once.  It might look like this<sup>2</sup>:

```js
const countBy = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => ((a [fn (x)] = (a [fn (x)] || 0) + 1), a), Object .create (null))
```

And we might use it like this:

```js
const decade = ({dob}) => `${dob .slice (0, 3)}0-${dob .slice (2, 3)}9`
const people = [{name: 'sue', dob: '1950-10-31'}, {name: 'bob', dob: '1967-04-28'},
                {name: 'jan', dob: '1972-02-26'}, {name: 'ron', dob: '1966-01-05'},
                {name: 'lil', dob: '1961-04-17'}, {name: 'tim', dob: '1958-09-12'}]

countBy (decade) (people) //=> {"1950-59": 2, "1960-69": 3, "1970-79": 1}
```

Now we can rewrite `count` to use this by passing an `identity` function to `countBy`.  `identity` is the trivial `(x) => x`, which turns out to be surprisingly useful:

```
const count = countBy (identity)
```

### Step 2: Separating the properties

So now we have `{M: 3, S: 6, R: 1, C: 1}`, but we need to turn this into an array of objects, one for each property.  There is a built-in JS function for this, `Object.entries`.  (Ramda has it's own version, `toPairs`, which predates `Object.entries`, but there is no reason now not to use the built-in one.)

So then we can do

```js
Object .entries ({M: 3, S: 6, R: 1, C: 1})
```

to get back

```js
[['M', 3], ['S', 6], ['R', 1], ['C', 1]]
```

### Step 3: Converting to final form, using `zipObj`

Now we want to convert, say `['M', 3]` to `{name: 'M', duplicates: 3}`.

One nice possibility is to write a `zip*` function that zips together two equal length lists into a new structure.  There are many possible variants, but let's write one that simply takes a list of keys and a same-sized list of values, and pairs them up as entries of an object<sup>3</sup>:

```js
const zipObj = (ks) => (vs) =>
  ks .reduce ((a, k, i) => ((a [k] = vs [i]), a), {})
```

and with this, we can call

```js
zipObj (['name', 'duplicates']) (['M', 3])
//=> {name: 'M', duplicates: 3}
```

### Step 4: `map`ping that result over all entries

We can now convert a single entry into its final form, but we have to do this with an array full of such entries.  We know how to do that using `Array.prototype.map`.  But there are two problems with using it directly.  One is a bit obscure: `Array.prototype.map` [passes additional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/262427/1243641) (the index and the whole array) besides our initial values.  There are times that can cause issues.  The second problem is simple: for the style promoted here, pure functions work much more nicely than object methods.

So we write a plain function `map`, which simply calls `Array.prototype.map`<sup>4</sup>:

```js
const map = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .map ((x) => fn (x))
```

and we can use it like this:

```js
map (zipObj (['name', 'duplicate'])) (
  [['M', 3], ['S', 6], ['R', 1], ['C', 1]]
)
```

which yields the final result.

It seems strange that after noting flaws in `Array.prototype.map`, we use it in the implementation of `map`, but I believe it makes sense.  We solve the second problem noted by the very fact that we're defining `map`.  And the first one is solved simply by managing `Array.prototype.map`, passing only the value into it.  Ramda rewrites these from scratch, and in doing so can eke out a bit more performance, but over time that performance edge is eroded, and the code there is much more cumbersome.

### Step 5: `pipe`ing these functions together

To make this a nice declarative set of steps, we need one more piece: a way to glue the functions together, to run one after another.  My image is of a pipeline through which the data flows, and so use `pipe` for this function.  This is a very close kin to the mathematical notion of function composition, and Ramda includes both `pipe` and `compose`, which work very similarly but list their arguments in opposite orders.

`pipe` is a simple function:

```js
const pipe = (...fns) => (x) =>
  fns .reduce ((a, fn) => fn (a), x)
```

We simply iterate over the functions, passing the result of the previous call to the next function, starting with the value passed in.

And with this, we can now put it all together.

### Step 6: Combining our functions

With all of the above, we now can write a solution to the original problem:

```js
const countBy = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => ((a [fn (x)] = (a [fn (x)] || 0) + 1), a), Object .create (null))
const identity = (x) => 
  x
const count = countBy (identity)
const zipObj = (ks) => (vs) =>
  ks .reduce ((a, k, i) => ((a [k] = vs [i]), a), {})
const map = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .map ((x) => fn (x))
const pipe = (...fns) => (x) =>
  fns .reduce ((a, fn) => fn (a), x)

const transform = pipe (
  countBy (identity),
  Object .entries,
  map (zipObj (['name', 'duplicates']))
)

const arr = ['M', 'M', 'M', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'C', 'S', 'S', 'S']

console .log (transform (arr))
console .log (transform (['toString', 'toString', 'valueOf']))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that the only custom code here is `transform`.  The rest is utility functions we can keep around for other parts of our system and for future systems.

### Lessons

- Small helper functions can be combined in powerful ways to make solutions to our larger problems easier to write.
- It pays to relentlessly break down code into smaller and smaller bits until we find those helper functions lurking in the problem.
- Once you have a significant collection of helper functions, it can become very quick to solve such problems.  I actually wrote [my solution](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20transform%20%3D%20pipe%20%28%0A%20%20countBy%20%28identity%29%2C%0A%20%20toPairs%2C%0A%20%20map%20%28zipObj%20%28%5B%27name%27%2C%20%27duplicates%27%5D%29%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%27M%27%2C%20%27M%27%2C%20%27M%27%2C%20%27S%27%2C%20%27S%27%2C%20%27S%27%2C%20%27R%27%2C%20%27C%27%2C%20%27S%27%2C%20%27S%27%2C%20%27S%27%5D%0A%0Atransform%20%28arr%29%0A) for this in Ramda in under two minutes.  The final version only differed in adding `count`, where the Ramda version requires `countBy (identity)` and in my use of Ramda's `toPairs` instead of `Object.entries`.

### Open Questions

- Performance: This is almost certainly not as performant as the answer from danh.  This one ends up looping over the data several times.  There are times when this is a real concern.  You will have to decide for your specific circumstances whether cleaner code is worth some inefficiencies.  There is no universal answer.  But I tend to prefer to run with the simplest code I can.  If my system speed does not meet my criteria, I profile to find the most important bottlenecks and solve those first.  Only very rarely has it come down to altering code like this.
- API design: I took the requested output as a hard requirement here.  And it may be; I don't know the OP's needs.  But I would find the output of `countBy`, `{M: 3, S: 6, R: 1, C: 1}` to be a more useful structure for most processing.  I would suggest always checking whether simpler structures might capture ones needs better than customized ones.

---

<sup>1</sup> The use of `Object .create (null)` instead of `{}` allows us to be able to handle the [issue georg raised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69418870/#comment122697703_69418930) in a comment to another answer.  By creating with a `null` prototype, we avoid spurious matches in our accumulator object for properties such as `'toString'`.

<sup>2</sup> We should probably note the inefficiency in `countBy`: it calculates `fn(x)` twice.  It's simple enough to fix this, but it takes us away from our main points here.  Honestly, I often don't bother, either.

<sup>3</sup> There is a whole family of functions that involve zipping two equal-sized arrays.  If we extend this, eventually we'll probably rewrite `zipObj` on top of a more generic `zipWith`, the way we rewrote `count` above atop `countBy`.  That's left as an exercise for the reader.

<sup>4</sup> Eventually, we might want to extend this function to also work on Objects, and perhaps other types.  But this is enough for now.

Comment: Really appreciate this long form answer. This has given me a lot to think about! However, for my use case, @danh's answer provided simplicity and ease, but maybe your answer will prove useful in later applications.