# Array grouping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to construct a mapping between this input and (intended) output data in JavaScript to produce a count of the number of times each year appears per category, but cant seem to figure it out ... could anyone offer a suggestion?

The intention is to populate a stacked line chart with a line for each category, plus an additional one for the total.

The input is of the form:

```
inputDates: [
    {
        title: 'categoryOne',
        years: ['2021', '2021', '2023', '2022', '2022', '2021']
    },
    {
        title: 'categoryTwo',
        years: ['2021', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2023']
    },
    {
        title: 'categoryThree',
        years: ['2022', '2023', '2023']
    },
]
```

And I'd like the output to look something like this

```
chartData: [
    {
        title: 'categoryOne',
        years: [
            {year: '2021', count: 3},
            {year: '2022', count: 2},
            {year: '2023', count: 1},
        ]
    },
        {
            title: 'categoryTwo',
            years: [
                {year: '2021', count: 1},
                {year: '2022', count: 4},
                {year: '2023', count: 1},
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'categoryThree',
            years: [
                {year: '2022', count: 1},
                {year: '2023', count: 2},
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'total',
            years: [
                {year: '2021', count: 4},
                {year: '2022', count: 7},
                {year: '2023', count: 4},
            ]
        },
]
```

Any thoughts/suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: see: [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Comment: also: [How to count the number of occurances in an array and translate it into an array of object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418870/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurances-in-an-array-and-translate-it-into-an-array)