# Using a function in Array.from

Tags: javascript

I would like to parse integers as they are written to a new array. Here are two versions I have:

```js
let aa = '123';
let bb = Array.from(aa, (val) => parseInt(val));
// [1,2,3] OK
let cc = Array.from(aa, parseInt);
// [1, NaN, NaN]
console.log(aa, bb, cc);
```

Why does the first method work, but the second method does not (doesn't `parseInt` take one required argument, so would be the same as the first method?)

Comment: _"doesn't parseInt take one argument"_... I guess you haven't [checked the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters)

Comment: @phil -- sure, the radix is optional though, so how is parseInt called in the above invocation?

Comment: It is the same reason as outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/262427/5648954

Comment: @David542 `Array.from(data, (el, index) =>` - you are passing the index as the second argument, which is then being treated as the radix

Comment: @dave thanks again. I think this is the correct answer, not quite touched on in the Duplicates from briefly glancing over some of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) takes two arguments, the second argument defines the radix (base) for the parsed number.

P. S. You could use the `Number` constructor as the second argument:

```
let cc = Array.from(aa, Number);
```

Comment: to expand, `Array.from` will pass `(element, index)`, so your radix will be the index of each element, causing undesirable results

Comment: @dave ah, got it. Yes I think that was actually what I didn't understand.