# At what index does the sum reach a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of numbers and some limit.

```js
const a = [1,2,1,3,4,1,2];
const limit = 5;
```

What's the most javascripty way of reducing this array to the index such that the sum from the beginning to the index would exceed the `limit`?

I've done

```js
function findIndex(nums, limit) {
      let s = 0;
      for (let [index, num] of nums.entries()) {
        s += num;
        if (s >= limit) {
          return index;
        }
      }
      return nums.length;
    }
```

```js
findIndex([1,2,1,3,4,1,2], 5)
3
```

Is there a more neat way of doing this using `reduce` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're after the index, you could look at using the array method [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). The below code adds to `sum` for each item in `arr`, and then checks whether the new accumulated `sum` value is greater than or equal to the limit. If it is, the callback for findIndex will return true, giving you the index of the item it returned true for. If the callback function to `findIndex` doesn't return true for any values, it will result in `-1`, which you can then check before you return to see if you need to return the array length or the found index:

```js
const findIndex = (arr, limit) => {
  let sum = 0;
  const idx = arr.findIndex((num, idx) => (sum+=num) >= limit);
  return idx > 0 ? idx : arr.length; 
}

console.log(findIndex([1,2,1,3,4,1,2], 5));
```

Comment: Or perhaps more simply: `(ns, limit, sum = 0) => ns .findIndex ((n) => (sum += n) > limit)`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Ah good suggestion, creating the local variable in the arguments of the function is a neat way to keep the arrow function body nice and concise

Comment: I like it and do it a lot, but it has its downside.  If passed to a function that supplies additional parameters, things can get screwed up.  Consider `const sum = (ns, t = 0) => ns .length ? sum (ns .slice (1), t + ns [0]) : t`.  Then `sum ([1, 2, 3, 4])` yields `10` as expected, but `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5]] .map (sum)` yields the incorrect `[6, 11]`, because `map` supplies the index and the whole array as additional parameters, and so for the second array, we start the `sum` at the index of `1` instead of `0`.  It's a useful technique, but we do have to be careful with it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I see, that's a good point and definitely something to look out for. That issue reminds me of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap) popular question with `parseInt()`

Answer (score 2):

Since you need the

**1)** `index` upto which the `sum` is greater or equal to `limit`

**2)** You want to `return` early as soon as the sum exceeds limit

then you should go for old school `for` loop. There is no need to accumulate the `index` and `value` using `nums.entries()`

```js
function findIndex(nums, limit) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
    sum += nums[i];
    if (sum >= limit) return i;
  }
  // Return something explicitely to 
  // indicate that sum can't exceeds limit.
  // You may return -1 if you like
}
console.log(findIndex([1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2], 5));
```