# parseInt is giving NaN when not using arrow function

Tags: javascript, nan, parseint

Why does `parseInt` give `NaN` when I am not putting it in an arrow function? What's strange is that only `50` is getting properly parsed, while the others are not... Is there something wrong with putting `parseInt` itself as an argument? I want to make sure all of them are whole numbers, it works with an arrow function but I would like to know why it doesn't work just passing in the whole function. Even trying to bind it to `window` with `.map(parseInt.bind(window))` doesn't work. Is it a problem with the source code?

```js
function toPercent(array) {
    let arr = array.map((a, _, s) => a / s.reduce((a, b) => a+b) * 100)
    console.log(arr)
    return arr.map(parseInt)
}

console.log(toPercent([2, 1, 1]))
```

```js
function toPercent(array) {
        let arr = array.map((a, _, s) => a / s.reduce((a, b) => a+b) * 100)
        console.log(arr)
        return arr.map(n => parseInt(n))
    }

    console.log(toPercent([2, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: What it looks like `return arr.map((n,index,array) => parseInt(n,index,array))` so you are setting the radix to be 1 and 2 for your number.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap?

Answer (score 0):

The callback to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is called with multiple parameters `(element, index, array)`, and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) takes multiple parameters `(string, radix)` so the `index` is being passed as the `radix`. That's probably not what you intended.

The NaNs arise because the radix must be between 2 and 36.  So you'll get some strange results radix is 1 and other indices will attempt to parse according to the ever-incrementing radix.  By even further quirkiness, radix 0 means to use base 10 (unless the string starts with `0x` or `0X`, in which case it means to use base 16 ignoring the prefix in the expected way). `parseInt` returns `NaN` when parsing fails.