# Javascript: Inconsistent behavior with bound function in `some` array function

Tags: javascript, binding

I'm trying to understand why this bound function is behaving differently when called in these different ways. Here's the example.

```js
var str = 'sss';
var f = str.endsWith.bind(str);

// false?
console.log(['s', 'q', 'r'].some(f))
// true
console.log(['s', 'q', 'r'].some(value => f(value)))
// true
console.log(f('s'))
```

What am I missing, why isn't the first call returning true?

Comment: Because the first example is also passing `index` and `arr` to `endsWith` and the [second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#parameters) of `endsWith` is `length` (it's equivalent to `.some((value, index, arr) => f(value, index, arr))`) see: [Why does parseInt yield NaN with Array#map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does parseInt yield NaN with Array#map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/why-does-parseint-yield-nan-with-arraymap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.some()` passes 3 arguments to the callback function: the current array element, its index, and the array.

`String.endswith()` takes an optional second argument, which is used as the length of the string instead of its actual length.

So the first iteration calls

```
f('s', 0, ['s', 'q', 'q'])
```

which is equivalent to

```
"sss".endsWith('s', 0)
```

If you use `0` as the length of the string, it doesn't end with `s`, so this returns `false`.

When you use your function `value => f(value)`, the extra arguments are discarded so the default length is used and the function operates as expected.